# how to add a variable of one module to another maodule in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I want add a variable from on module to another module ,

at the same time i have doubts in declaring variable.**

THIS IS MY MAIN PROGRAM

```
import check
print("enter your name")
name=input()
if check.users:
 print("nice to see yo again")
else :
 print("nice to meet you")
```

This is my another file check.py

```
import new
users = name=="venkatesh" or name=="rishi" or name=="arjun"
```

but the compiler shows the error message:

```
CHECK MODULE HAS NO ATTRIBUTE OF USERS
```

Comment: be sure of the language you're coding in.

Comment: How is this question related to Java or C++?

Comment: use `module.variable`. I think it must be `new.name` in your case

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

`new.py` file.

```
import check

user = check.user
print("enter your name")
name=input()
if check.users:
    print("nice to see yo again")
else :
    print("nice to meet you")
```

`check.py` file

```
user = "Enter name of the User"
# Your check condition
```

Comment: No it show the error again  like attributeerror : module 'check' has no attribute 'users'

Comment: your question is not clear enough. Which variable you want to use in other module?

Comment: "users" variable in check.py file to main page